# Multi-entity Aggregates command handling

Tags: axon

I have an aggregate root like this:

Aggregate root:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Aggregate(repository = "positionAggregateRepository")
@AggregateRoot
@XSlf4j
@Data
public class HopAggregate {

@AggregateIdentifier
private String hopId;
private FilteredPosition position;
private LocalDate positionDate;
@AggregateMember
private Security security;

@CommandHandler
public HopAggregate(NewHopCommand cmd) {
    log.info("creating new position , {}", cmd.getDateId());
    apply(new HopEvent(cmd.getHopId(), cmd.getDateId(), cmd.getFilteredPosition(), cmd.getSecurity(), false));
}

@CommandHandler
public void handle(UpdateHopCommand cmd) {
    log.info("creating hop update event {}", cmd);
    apply(new HopEvent(this.hopId, this.positionDate, cmd.getFilteredPosition(), this.security, true));
}

@CommandHandler
public void handle(SecurityUpdate cmd) {
    log.info("updating security {}", cmd);
    apply(new SecurityUpdateEvent(this.hopId, cmd.getFilteredSecurity()));
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(HopEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getIsUpdate()) {
        log.info("updating position {}", evt);
        this.position = evt.getFilteredPosition();
    } else {
        log.info("adding new position to date {}", evt);
        this.hopId = evt.getHopId();
        this.positionDate = evt.getDate();
        this.position = evt.getFilteredPosition();
        this.security= evt.getSecurity();
    }
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(SecurityUpdateEvent evt) {
    log.info("hop id {}, security update {}", this.hopId, evt.getFilteredSecurity().getSecurityId());
}
```

}

Child entity:

```
@XSlf4j
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class IpaSecurity implements Serializable {

@EntityId
@NonNull
private String id;
@NonNull
private FilteredSecurity security;
}
```

My issue is that when i am pushing and update like this:

```
@EventHandler
public void handleSecurityEvent(SecurityUpdate securityUpdate) {
log.info("got security event {}", securityUpdate);
commandGateway.send(securityUpdate);
}
```

and my command being:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SecurityUpdate {

@NonNull
@TargetAggregateIdentifier
private String id;
@NonNull
private FilteredSecurity filteredSecurity;
}
```

I am getting aggregate root not found exception:

Command 'com.hb.apps.ipa.events.SecurityUpdate' resulted in org.axonframework.modelling.command.AggregateNotFoundException(The aggregate was not found in the event store)

I am not sure how to handle this scenario. My requirement is that each aggregate should check whether it contains the security and then update it if the command was issued. What am i missing? let me know if you need any more info on the code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to apply event to all aggregates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Command is always targeted towards *a single entity*.
This entity can be an Aggregate, an entity contained in an Aggregate (what Axon Framework calls an Aggregate Member) or a simple singleton component.
Important to note though, is that *there will only be one* entity handling the command.

This is what requires you to set the `@TargetAggregateIdentifier` in your Command for Axon to be able to route it to a single Aggregate instance if the Command Handler in question is part of it.

The `AggregateNotFoundException` you're getting signals that the `@TargetAggregateIdentifier` annotated field in your `SecurityUpdate` command does no correspond to any existing Aggregate.
I'd thus suspect that the `id` field in the `SecurityUpdate` does not correspond to any `@AggregateIdentifier` annotated field in your `HopAggregate` aggregates.

A part from the above, I have a couple of other suggestions when looking at your snippets which I'd like to share with you:

- `@Aggregate` is meta-annotated with `@AggregateRoot`. You're thus not required to specify both on an Aggregate class
- For logging messages being handled, you can utilize `LoggingInterceptor`. You can configure this on any component capable of handling messages, thus providing a universal way of logging. This will omit the necessity to add log lines in your message handling functions
- You're publishing a `HopEvent` on both the create and update commands. Doing so makes your `HopEvent` very generic. Ideally, your events clarify business operations occurring in your system. My rule of thumb typically is such: "If I tell my business manager/customer about the event class, he/she should know exactly what it does". I'd thus suggest to rename the event to something more specific
- Just as with the `HopEvent`, the `UpdateHopCommand` is quite generic. Your commands should express the intent to perform an operation in your application. Users will typically not desire an update, they desire an address change for example. Your commands classes ideally reflect this
- The suggested naming convention for commands is to start with verb in the present tense. Thus, it should no be `SecurityUpdate`, but `UpdateSecurity`. A command is *a request expressing intent*, the messages ideally reflect this

Hope this helps you out @juggernaut!

Comment: Thanks Steven, This is very helpful. This code is still initial stages of development and therefore is note functionally complete. You made some great suggestions that i will definitelytake into account and updat this.

Comment: Regarding Aggregate not found error, ID field in securityUpdate is the id that EntityId in member aggregate and not AggregateIdentitier. Since i want this update to be applied to all memberaggregates and do not have the aggregateIdentifier for HopAggregate, how do i make this work?

Comment: For a Command to be directed to an Aggregate Member within an Aggregate Root, you are required to have knowledge of the external reference towards that Aggregate Root, being the Aggregate Identifier. Thus there is no way for the framework to know how to route a Command which only contains the Aggregate Member Identifier, you will have to add the Aggregate Identifier somehow.